# Derailleur can't shift to 51-T sprocket. Deore CS-M5100 + RD-M5100

Tags: shimano, cassette, derailleur-rear, shifting, 1x11

**ISSUE:**
When attempting to shift to the largest cassette sprocket, the side of the derailleur cage contacts the 51t sprocket, so the chain is not able to go up the gear.

**WHAT I DID:**
My drivetrain was in need of a replacement, so I decided to change to a 1x11 (from my original 2x11 CANYON Neuron AL 6.9 2017).

- I replaced my SLX M7000, 11x42 tooth, 11-speed cassette with the Deore CS-M5100-11, 11x51 tooth.
- Replaced my Deore XT Shadow derailleur with the Deore RD-M5100-SGS.
- I also changed my chain and chainring, but that irrelevant for now.

**ELABORATION:**

- The stopper plate properly contacts the B-tension stop on the derailleur hanger.
- The limit screws are adjusted (so far as possible)
- Shortened the new chain to zero point + 4 links + quick link
- The B-screw is maxed, all the way screwed against the stop to push the derailleur back.
  If I would pull the chain (making the effect if it would be shorter) the cage gets pulled to the front of the bike and clearing the 51t sprocket. Albeit, just. So shortening the chain is not the option, seems to me.

**UPDATE:**
I contacted Canyon, with my question if I might need another derailleur hanger/pad. They said this is the correct 11-speed hanger.

[Manual RD-M5100-SGS](https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/dm/MARD001/DM-MARD001-03-ENG.pdf)

[image]

Not enough space between top of cage and 51T sprocket

[image: Can't reach 51t]

Can't reach 51t, left side of the cage is touching the sprocket

[image: Chain on the 10th sprocket]

Chain on the 10th sprocket

[image: Chain on the smallest 11T sprocket]

Chain on the smallest 11T sprocket, if the chain would be longer then there is no tension

[image: promotional material]

In all promotional material, the derailleur hanger seems to be quite a bit more downwards and not to the back (unlike my derailleur hanger/pad)

[image: Stopper plate]

Stopper plate in correct place between derailleur pad/hanger and B-screw.  B-screw is also maxed inwards.

[image: current hanger]

current hanger

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out this derailleur needs a 'standard mount' derailleur pad/hanger. I have currently a direct mount.

The Canyon representative thought the SRAM hanger was for 10 speed.

To me, it is now clear that a 'SRAM' pad/hanger is the same as a Shimano 'standard mount'. So, I purchased the SRAM hanger (aka standard mount) from Canyon and it works!

Comment: Excellent work - thank you for coming back to provide closure.  Future searchers will be grateful.

Comment: I went from 2x11 XT M8000 to 1x11 M5100 and I am having same issue as you. I got a Canyon Spectral with same original hanger as you. (no 27). What is the number on the hanger you bought, please?

Comment: @stoffn I ordered Derailleur Hanger GP0155-01, which was the only other option really. As I stated in my answer I had a standard mount derailleur hanger, and then bought a direct mount (Canyon called it a SRAM hanger). Look up the Canyon spec sheet pdf for your options.